# Rich text copy-paste from Visual Studio line spacing issue

Tags: c#, visual-studio, text-editor, rich-text-editor

In Visual Studio (2019, 2022 etc.) I have enabled this option in order to copy-paste code that is syntax highlighted:

```
Tools\Options\Text Editor\Advanced\Copy rich text on copy/cut
```

[image: screenshot]

This is a feature I've used for a very long time (so long in fact that I hope this isn't just my feeble mind giving out). The way that I *recall* this working is that a paste operation into Word or WordPad or a RichTextBox would look identical to the source with no added spacing after NewLine or Paragraph. For example:

**Good**

```
static class Extensions
{
    public static void RunWithWrapper(this Action action, [CallerMemberName] string caller = null)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"The {caller} method has been invoked.");
        action();
    }
}
```

---

Lately, however, this is producing *bad* behavior. My question is whether there's a new switch for this somewhere because "every so often" Visual Studio will add some new option and enable it by default (essentially making a breaking change to how one is accustomed to the IDE behaving).

I'm looking for *any* way to avoid having the pasted code look like this:

**Bad**

```
static class Extensions

{

    public static void RunWithWrapper(this Action action, [CallerMemberName] string caller = null)

    {

        Debug.WriteLine($"The {caller} method has been invoked.");

        action();

    }

}
```

And yes, it's important (at least to me) I use this constantly.

Comment: When I copy it into word, if I choose to keep the source format, it will be your "good", if I choose other formats, such as clearing the format, the spacing will be abnormal. Maybe you just didn't choose the correct paste format? Does your "bad" also appear when pasting into vs? Have you turned on [automaticlly format on paste](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4xJM.png)?

Comment: @JialeXue-MSFT thx your comment is providing me with several ways to move this forward. I read it and thought _"I'm sure I tested it in both Word and WordPad"_ but today the result is WordPad **bad** and Word **good**. Ok,  so my _real_ concern was that my stable production app (DevExpress RichTextEditor) started behaving differently. But the issue was reproducible in WordPad and so I thought making that the minimal reproducible sample would help but may have inadvertently turned it into an x-y problem instead (boo). I am grateful to you for making me redo my Word v WordPad test BIG CLUE.